# Нужны ли кавычки в следующем афоризме?

Tags: орфография

Кованый афоризм не изменить. Нужно ли какое-то слово(а) выделить кавычками. Как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Кованый афоризм не изменить.

Кавычки не нужны, кованый - это переносное значение слова, основанное на метафоре (скрытом сравнении).

Из словаря: КОВАНЫЙ, 1. Изготовленный посредством ковки. 4. **Чёткий, выразительный, чеканный** (о стихе, стиле и т.п.). Звучат к-ые строфы поэмы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!